# How to deploy public PHP files in Magento 2 extension?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, composer, deployment

I need to deploy a publicly accessible PHP file as part of a Magento 2 extension. Obviously this is not intended, as usually all requests should be routed through `index.php`, but in this case it's needed for performance optimization.

Is it possible to do this **without requiring manual installation steps** (i.e. copy files to `/pub`)?

I thought about making it a static asset, but the PHP engine is disabled by default in `pub/static` for good reasons.

Can I use the Magento composer installer in some way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First part is how to do this from an extension builder perspective. I'm leaving the second part as reference for project builders.

**Extension builder answer:**

You can't do this from within an extension which has

```
...
"type": "magento2-module"
...
```

in its composer.json file.

You will need to create a new/extra extension for these files. This new extension will have a composer.json as follows:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/magento-module-foomodule-files",
    "description": "Extra files for vendor/magento-component-foomodule",
    "require": {
        ...
    },
    "type": "magento2-component",
    "extra": {
        "map": [
           "pub_scripts/*",
           "pub_scripts"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Update your module's composer.json to require this new extension:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/magento-module-foomodule",
    ...
    "require": {
        "vendor/magento-module-foomodule-files": "*"
    }
    ...
}
```

During installation all files from /path/to/webroot/vendor/Vendor/magento-module-foomodule-files/pub_scripts/ directory will be copied to /path/to/webroot/pub_scripts/

**Project builder answer:**

You will have to write your own post install commands for composer. This is relatively simple though. Add the 'scripts' node to your composer.json as follows:

```
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "scripts/post-install-cmd/deploy.sh"
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: this is the composer.json file in the root of your project.

And the script itself: scripts/post-install-cmd/deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

WEBROOT=/path/to/webroot

#copy file(s) (never move files away from vendor)
cp "${WEBROOT}/vendor/Vendor/Module/files/file1.php" "${WEBROOT}/pub_scripts/file1.php"
cp "${WEBROOT}/vendor/Vendor/Module/files/file2.php" "${WEBROOT}/pub_scripts/file2.php"
```

In this example I copy the files to the 'pub_scripts' directory. This directory will need to exist.

- Replace Vendor/Module in the file path with you own values of course.
- Make sure that files in the 'scripts' and 'pub_scripts' directories are not publicly accessible. Deny all access to the 'scripts' directory and use htaccess login and/or IP whitelist for the 'pub_scripts' directory.

Your script(s) are now available for you at

- http://www.example.com/pub_scripts/file1.php
- http://www.example.com/pub_scripts/file2.php

Comment: Works like a charm, I can even replace `"pub_scripts"` with `""` to deploy directly to the document root. Actually I used both "pub" and "" as target because the document root might be "pub" as well.

Comment: "pub_scripts" was completely arbitrary :) basically whatever you use will map to the document root

Comment: Can you tell me the folder structure, how to keep that external php file in my package folder.( I mean inside my zip file which I will upload in marketplace)

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Can you please guide me to create my composer file.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal I don't think you can upload the two(!) packages to the marketplace together. You probably need to put the one with the public scripts to github and add it as dependency.